# Weird x labels with stacked area chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: stacked area chart]

Anyone know why I'm getting these odd x-axis labels? The original code had the commented line, which produced similar results, so I tried the alphabetical list to check what was causing the problem and got the same result.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np
input_file = 'CSP.csv'
output_file = 'sub_plots.png'
y = []
#susbset to SDs first
df1 = df[(df.Class=='FIR')]
x = np.arange(len(df1.ix[:,0]))
for i in range(8):
    y.append(df1.ix[:,i+7])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','aa','ab','ac']
ax.stackplot(x,y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3],y[4],y[5],y[6],y[7])
#labels = [str(i) for i in list(df1.Local_Authority)]
plt.xticks(x,labels,size='small')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.savefig(output_file_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that [`get_majorticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_majorticklabels) returns a list of [`Text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects and [`set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) accepts a list of strings as the first input. Therefore, since you are passing this list of `Text` objects to `set_xticklabels`, the `Text` objects are getting coerced into strings which is giving you the xtick labels that you're seeing.

To fix this, you will need to get the actual labels from the existing ticks and pass these to `set_xticklabels()`

```
labels = [label.get_text() for label in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
```

Alternately, it looks like you've already created a list of strings to use as the labels, so you can really just use that directly.

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', .....]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm getting confused as each time I want to do something new like rotate text or change the labels I google how to do it, but then when I combine all these approaches they don't match up.